# Pretty URLs and custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I've read the posts on WP SA on rewrites and custom post types, but I can't figure out why my search for 2 different post types isn't working.

I'd like my URLS to become `example.com/search/events/searchtem` and `example.com/search/artists/searchterm`.

I have a CPT called 'events' and one called 'artists'. My custom permalink structure is set to `/%postname%/`.

My search forms:

```
<form class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url('/events/'); ?>" method="get">
<input id="s" name="s" type="text" class="span4" />
<input class="search-button" type="submit" value="Zoek" tabindex="-1" />
</form>

<form class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url('/artists/'); ?>" method="get">
<input id="s" name="s" type="text" class="span4" />
<input class="search-button" type="submit" value="Zoek" tabindex="-1" />
</form>
```

If I search, the URLs become `example.com/events/?s=searchterm` and `example.com/artists/?s=searchterm` but the return a 404. This is weird, because putting `?s=` behind any URL turns it into a query right? These are the results with the nice-search functions (see below) disabled or enabled (no difference).

If I change `<?php echo home_url('/events/'); ?>` to `<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>` and add `<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="events" />` with nice-search (see below) disabled everything works as expected (URL becomes `example.com/?post_type=events&s=searchterm`). With nice-search enabled, the results become example.com/search/searchterm (so it does rewrite) and it does take me to my search results page but it searches everything instead of just one post type.

The functions from nice-search (I'm using the roots theme) which consists of two parts:

```
function roots_nice_search_redirect() {
  global $wp_rewrite;
  if (!isset($wp_rewrite) || !is_object($wp_rewrite) || !$wp_rewrite->using_permalinks()) {
    return;
  }

  $search_base = $wp_rewrite->search_base;
  if (is_search() && !is_admin() && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/{$search_base}/") === false) {
    wp_redirect(home_url("/{$search_base}/" . urlencode(get_query_var('s'))));
    exit();
  }
} 
if (current_theme_supports('nice-search')) {
  add_action('template_redirect', 'roots_nice_search_redirect');
}
```

and

```
function roots_request_filter($query_vars) {
  if (isset($_GET['s']) && empty($_GET['s'])) {
    $query_vars['s'] = ' ';
  }

  return $query_vars;
} 
add_filter('request', 'roots_request_filter');
```

After reading the posts, I think I need to alter my rewrite function but I don't really know how to...

Also, I'd like to use `<?php echo home_url('/events/'); ?>` instead of `<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="events" />` if possible and I don't use pagination.

Comment: I hope anyone can point me in the right direction...